# C4 persistence -- does it depend on where you plant it?

Tags: battlefield-3

I find that when I die sometimes my C4 stays put and sometimes it's gone, but I can't be sure without any controlled testing.

It seems to me that if I put C4 on the ground, then die, I can still blow it up once I respawn.

But if I am killed after placing my C4 on an enemy vehicle, once I respawn I never am able to kill that vehicle by using my detonator.

Does the game remove them upon death only when they are placed on enemy vehicles?

Comment: Note: this is all going to change in the next patch. From patch notes: -C4 will no longer be detonable after a player respawns, if the player is revived within 5 seconds he can still detonate his C4.

Comment: Yeah, I read that (really long) list of changes. I think they are going in the right direction with it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am almost positive C4 has the same rules as mines.  On the ground, they will stay there until they are blown up / triggered.  Although, when you place C4 on vehicles and then die, you are correct:  The game will remove those items.  I assume they set that up so players cannot camp enemy vehicle spawns through lives.

**EDIT**

> C4 will no longer be detonable after a player respawns, if the player
>   is revived within 5 seconds he can still detonate his C4.

As apart of the patch notes released on March 27 [See here for more info.](http://bf3blog.com/2012/03/battlefield-3-patch-coming-march-27-on-the-ps3/)

Comment: That makes sense. There are definitely nasty options that open up if they did persist that way.

Comment: Exactly.  If this helped, please up vote / Check :)

Comment: Could this be platform specific?  I remember seeing a video of someone spawning US, planting C4 on their heli, suiciding, switching teams, spawning, then detonating and killing everyone in the heli.

Comment: Claymores never persist after death - they always disappear, regardless of their placement

Comment: Good catch @SSumner, I have provided edits.

Comment: I am 99% sure that Claymores do persist after death. I've planted one, died, and came back and it was still there.

Comment: I know they can last for some time, but not nearly as long as mines.  [from my experience] I just know definiatively that C4 behaves the same as mines.

Comment: Here is a recent example showing C4 detonated on a helicopter after a respawn. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oeWLdUJlmQ&t=0m50s

Comment: See my edit per the new patch that came out.

Answer (score 5):

C4 does not behave the same as the tank mines. If you plant C4 and die, the C4 is removed. Perhaps there was a coincidental explosion at a time that made you believe that your C4 had persisted?

Here is the link from Dec 11:

http://www.battlefieldhq.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=60&Itemid=361

Comment: No I'm pretty sure it works like mines do when you place them on the ground.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll test again. I was sure the explosion was mine when I did it, and this was like 3 days ago.

Comment: Doesn't get any more correct then from DICE themselves.

Comment: The linked article starts with "a list of possible future changes to Battlefield 3" and "The items listed aren’t 100% certain to make it to a future patch". So the point "C4 will no longer be detonatable after a player respawns, if the player is revived within 5 seconds he can still detonate his C4." is only proposed at this stage.

Answer (score 3):

Fact: C4 will persist on vehicles after you die.

New fact: This will change with the next patch.

Comment: There are a lot of conflicting reports for this question! I did get a vehicle destroy when I detonated upon respawn yesterday, but I couldn't be sure because I did leave some C4 on the ground also and the guy could have driven over it. Damn this is going to take some real team effort mythbusting. Who's up for it? I'm on PC and my bf3 soldier is dc443, friend me.

Comment: I did it last night in a SQDM. Might have to fraps it next time

Answer (score 2):

On the PS3 if I die when planting C4 on an enemy vehicle I immediately hit the detonator trigger when I respawn. The majority of the time I will either get the vehicle disabled or destroyed notification. Perhaps this is a glitch in the PS3 version but there is some persistence of C4 after getting killed.

[Youtube video showing C4 trigger on vehicle after respawn](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oeWLdUJlmQ&t=0m50s).

Comment: I do the same on PC. So there could be some leeway when you respawn maybe possible potentially....